# Rails XML parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing

Can anybody tell me how to parse this on rails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message>
  <param>
    <name>messageType</name>
    <value>SMS</value>
  </param>
  <param>
    <name>id</name>
    <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
  </param>
  <param>
    <name>source</name>
    <value>xxxxxxxxxxx</value>
  </param>
  <param>
    <name>target</name>
    <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
  </param>
  <param>
    <name>msg</name>
    <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
  </param>
  <param>
    <name>udh</name>
    <value></value>
  </param>
</message>
```

I have no control on this xml, but I hope I can make the parameter looks like this before saving to my database

```
message"=>{"msg"=>"sampler", "id"=>"1", "target"=>"23123", "source"=>"312321312"}
```

here is the parameter I received when it access my method

```
message"=>{"param"=>[{"name"=>"id", "value"=>"2373084120100804002252"}, {"name"=>"messageType", "value"=>"SMS"}, {"name"=>"target", "value"=>"23730841"}, {"name"=>"source", "value"=>"09156490046"}, {"name"=>"msg", "value"=>"Hello world via iPhone"}, {"name"=>"udh", "value"=>nil}]}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are a lot of Ruby XML parsing libraries. However, if your XML is small, you can use the ActiveSupport Hash extension [`.from_xml`](https://devdocs.io/rails~5.2/hash#method-c-from_xml):

```ruby
Hash.from_xml(x)["message"]["param"].inject({}) do |result, elem| 
  result[elem["name"]] = elem["value"] 
  result 
end
# => {"msg"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "messageType"=>"SMS", "udh"=>nil, "id"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "target"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "source"=>"xxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: oh dude can you help me, what if the input is from @message = Message.new(params[:message]).. I don't know how to insert it on the X .. it gives me a NIL result

I'm using this but it doesnt work mobi = (params[:message]).to_xml

Comment: how to make it work from this code :D

      @message = Message.new(params[:message])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @message.save
          format.html { redirect_to(@message, :notice => 'Message was successfully created.') }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @message, :status => :created, :location => @message }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @message.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

Answer (score 17):

You should use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for parsing xml. Its pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

Also, try checking out [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) for more complex problems.