# How to I GET an XML page and parse it into a Ruby hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

Assuming my xml response is at `example.com/query`, how do I parse it into a Ruby hash without using external dependencies like Nokogiri?

Also, and not really part of the question, why would anyone use XML?

Comment: Have a look at this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403079/rails-xml-parsing

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = 'example.com/query'
h = Hash.from_xml(open url)
```

This example needs `Hash#from_xml` from Rail's `active_support/core_ext/hash` and will not work with Vanilla Ruby.